# Error checking out license: System clock has been set back

Tags: datetime, azure, licensing

On Azure CentOS VM while starting a custom application server that rely on FLEXnet license, I got the following error:

```
Error checking out license: System clock has been set back.
Feature:       ep_u
License path:  /opt/MyApplication/license/MyApplication-license.dat:
FLEXnet Licensing error:-88,309
For further information, refer to the FLEXnet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
```

After searching on the net, I found that this error is due to some system file modified in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't found a clear response to this issue, I write my own.

First on centOS I could check the current timezone:

```
ls -l /etc/localtime
```

And eventually update it

```
timedatectl list-timezones | grep Paris
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
```

Then I need to check if my system have directories or files with a date in the future:

```
cd /
sudo find . -newermt "1 days"|more
```

I dont know why I have some results here but this command return me a lots of files and directory, event virtual file like `/dev /sys /proc`...

I finally fix this issue by updating timestamp of some working files/directory. In the previous results I fixed `/etc` and `/var` directories.

Here is the command to fix (reset future date) a given directory content (ex. `/var`) and set the current date for each entry (having a date in the future) :

```
cd /var
sudo find . -newermt "1 days"|sudo xargs touch
```

hope this helps

Comment: You should accept your answer too, and then delete this comment. Since this is the right approach.

Comment: make sure you also run find with -newerat to find files with an access time in the future

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can help:

```
$ cd /
$ touch ref_file
$ find . -newer ref_file
$ find . -newer ref_file -exec touch {} \;
```